# php - required help in creating dynamic column names

Tags: php, html

I've successfully connected PostgreSQL database using PHP. And I can run queries in it.

Now that I wanted to populate week wise data.

I have some challenge in making the table header dynamic according to the number of weeks passed.

For the current month we are on week 2. So I've got two elements in an array namely `Week 1` and `Week 2`.

But the table header are defined manually to max `Week 5` which I wanted to make it dynamic to the number of weeks passed i.e., 2.

Here are the code.

```
$week_num = ceil(date('d') / 7);

for ( $i = 1; $i < $week_num + 1; $i++ ) {
        $week_table_header[] = 'Week '. $i;
    }
```

Which gives me this result.

```
Array ( [0] => Week 1 [1] => Week 2 )
```

I have this table header created using php.

```
echo "<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Week 1</th>
                <th>Week 2</th>
                <th>Week 3</th>
                <th>Week 4</th>
                <th>Week 5</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>";
```

Where I need to get only `Week 1` and `Week 2` in the table.

I tried using forEach.

```
   foreach ($week_table_header as $table_header) {
        # code...
        $str =  "<th>". $table_header ."</th>";

    }
```

And concatenated with the echo of the table. I got only `Week 2` which the last element in the array.

And the entire table is populated with this query.

```
while ( $row_week = pg_fetch_assoc($week_query)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row_week['Week 1'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row_week['Week 2'] . "</td>";
    // echo "<td>" . $row_week['Week 3'] . "</td>";
    // echo "<td>" . $row_week['Week 4'] . "</td>";
    // echo "<td>" . $row_week['Week 5'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Even here I need to make the column names to be dynamic.

Some one help me out how can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not much code to go on, but you probably want `$str +=  "<th>". $table_header ."</th>";`. Note the `+=` to add new content to the existing string.

Comment: If i add that `+-` i get error as undefined variable `str`.

Comment: Set `$str = '';` before the loop and use `+=` inside.

Answer (score 0):

in your for each loop

```
 $str="";
foreach ($week_table_header as $table_header) {
    # code...
    $str=  $str."<th>". $table_header ."</th>";

}
```

and in your while loop

```
echo "<tr>";
while ( $row_week = pg_fetch_assoc($week_query)) {
//your code
}
echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score -1):

If you only need the first two weeks you can have a fixed number of iterations

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < 2; $i++ ) {
    $week_table_header[] = 'Week '. ($i + 1);
}
```

If you want `$i` to start at 1 set `$i = 1; $i < 3; $i++` instead.

Comment: I know about that. I want to put that result to the html table header using php dynamically if there's more weeks are added.